# How do you install cx_Oracle for Python on RHEL?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, rhel

I'm using Active Python since I don't want to be stuck with an old version of Python. I installed the instant client, and added the exports to my bash profile, but I'm getting this cryptic error:

```
# apy setup.py install --no-compile --root=/tmp/tmpz0JuWASA/cx_Oracle-5.1/_pypminstroot
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/sdk/include -I/opt/ActivePython-2.7/include/python2.7 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.0.4
In file included from /opt/ActivePython-2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from cx_Oracle.c:6:
/opt/ActivePython-2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:849:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
In file included from /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/sdk/include/oci.h:3029,
                 from cx_Oracle.c:10:
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/sdk/include/ociap.h:10788: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/sdk/include/ociap.h:10794: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I took all of this from this blog [here](http://ubuntugeeknerd.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-oxoracle-in-rhel-64-bit.html) if you need more details.

I did this and it worked perfectly. Here is the quick summary. 
First go get the oracle client stuff for your version of oracle (link is in blog)

Then download to your /tmp/ folder and run the install

```
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.4-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Now this was the part I struggled with, make sure ALL of your environmental variables are right. Also don't just copy these, go and confirm where your oracle stuff was installed.

```
echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64/lib/ >> ~/.bashrc
echo export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64 >> ~/.bashrc
echo export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can go to the ox_Oracle site, make sure to download the version that matches your version of python (if you are not sure run python -V) and your version of the oracle driver.

Download to your TMP folder, install and test with

```
python -c "import cx_Oracle"
```

If that doesn't work check that blog, maybe I missed something. It worked for me on a fresh install. Thank goodness.

Sorry... not enough reputation points to give more live links... so you have to copy and paste or go to the blog.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've a client sdk present in your path. Oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm which I tried did not come with the sdk. So I had to download zip version for it.

Add this to .bash_rc

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
```

In addition to this, Python 2.7 does not come with Python.h which is available by default in Python 3.4. So I would also suggest to install python-devel package

```
yum install python-devel
```

That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

First off, active state distribution is another distribution, it always follows the release from python.org. So you get the latest release from python.org too. I think, you meant the system installed python which can be bit older.

Secondly, in your Redhat installation check if you have installed development tools and headers like gcc, glibc etc and [here](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/BUILD.txt) are some build instructions which are given at cx_Oracle page. make sure you have followed them.

Comment: I never said which py i was talking about, I just meant that I don't want to use python 2.4 which comes with RHEL. I followed the directions perfectly. Those instructions are not working and GCC is failing.